# Mobile Application Question

Tags: c#, .net, mobile

I have To develop one sample mobile applciation for ( meter reading )...
In this i stored the data in sqlce ,,,,
then i want to integrate the sqlce data to any ERP like accpac,crm...
Pls give idea about that integration...

Thank u Regards

Answer (score 1):

The path to integration is going to depend entirely on the extensibility and import capabilities of the ERP software. Dive into the documentation to see what and how you can import data into that system, and then design your integration mechanism around that.

Answer (score 0):

I know accpac has the capacity to be integrated with. It's not an easy process, but once you get over the learning curve, it goes quick. 
I'd take the contents of your mobile data, and store it on the desk.  View it as a staging system.  Something that holds all the data on your handheld. 
Make the mobile device sync with that first. 
Then sync that db with the third parties.
It will save on bandwidth to and from the mobile device, and you can make use of a much faster net connection when sync'ing with the "others".